# Visual Studio Team Services Build variables find and replace - Productivity tip

Tags: visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

If have to change the Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) build variables, i need to manually edit every variable, is there any way to perform Find and Replace build variables? Similarly if I need to revert the changes to previous version again I need to manually update each variable by looking into the previous version.

Is there any productivity tip/better way to handle working with Build variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to search and replace the build variables directly. But there are several useful extensions you can use to manage your variables. For example: [Variable Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks) and [Variables Tasks Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.VariableTasks).

And for reverting the changes to previous version, MS is already working on this. Refer to this link for details: [provide a way to version-control build definitions](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037625-provide-a-way-to-version-control-build-definitions).